# Installing mongodb with homebrew only installed an empty folder

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb using homebrew on my mac ios version 10.10.2. The install looks like it went ok but the mongodb directory is empty. /usr/local/var/mongodb

Shouldn't that directory contain the newly installed mongodb?

`brew install mongodb`

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mongodb-3.0.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mongodb-3.0.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mongodb-3.0.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
To have launchd start mongodb at login:
    ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mongodb/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mongodb now:
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.1: 17 files, 153M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binaries `mongod` and `mongo` install in /usr/local/bin/mongodb

```
ls -lsa /usr/local/bin/mongodb/bin
```

The database location -- since you mention `var` -- is `/data/db` that can be viewed when kicking of the `mongod` process

```
$ /usr/local/bin/mongodb/bin/mongod

 MongoDB starting : pid=12379 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=HostessTwinkies.local
```

Answer (score 0):

This folder is supposed to be empty to start. Homebrew creates the mongodb config (/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf) which sets up the database path to be that directory.

dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb